# How to give access to a user on only two specified procedures and specified tables on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We would like to introduce an external orchestrator in order to feed some tables from two stored procedures on SQL Server. However, we will need to create an 'orchstr' user for the orchestrator.
We want to give access to the user 'orchstr' to execute only the two specified stored procedures (so there is a restriction on the other procedures). And access on the tables to be fed only.

Is it possible? How could we do this?

I'm still a beginner, it would be too kind of you to help me.

We have SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bu default, a user don't have any premissions. So, all you have to do is to grant the permissions you want:

```
GRANT EXEC ON proname TO usrname
GRANT SELECT ON tablename TO username
```

I don't understand what you mean by "tables to be fed".

If a proc operates on a table (SELECT, INSERT ...) then it is enough to have EXEC permissions on the proc, you don't need the (SELECT, INSERT...) privilege on the table in order to execute the proc. This assumes the same over of the proc as the table, called "ownership chaining".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very much possible. First you need to add that login as a user in the database without any explicit database role assigned except public role(no server role as well). Once login is added as a user in the database, you need to execute grant permission as below:

```
use db_name
go
grant execute on dbo.Proc_Name1 to User_name
go
grant execute on dbo.Proc_Name2 to User_name
go
grant select on dbo.Table_name to User_name
go
```

In above example, I am considering you are having default schema(dbo). If there is non dbo schema then you need to prefix accordingly.
You may read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple objects inside your stored procedures.
Then you can try with execute as owner option in your stored procedure.
No need to give individual permissions for objects used in stored procedures.